# Could not make some elements responsive on the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a home page and before was responsive and I have added 2 buttons, 1 text and 3 images that I used them as background and the response is gone if I try to make the window smaller the page get broken or even for the mobile version. As I am very beginner with flex-layout I try some things but I am out of the idea, I hope if anyone can help me solve this problem.
the problem is in I have to underline with the yellow in the images shown below they are not responsive and I have applied many ideas on their style. but still can fix it. I want them to be responsive, what I mean is that if I make the window smaller they have the same position and if is the mobile version the become smaller but the must remain in their positions and so far they are not.

```css
:host {
  // background: #d0d0d094;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #5674f7 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%), #35adda;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  // background-image: url("assets/images/background.svg");
}

.header {
  min-height: 80vh;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.header__container {
  padding-top: 12rem;
}

#home {
  // background: linear-gradient(59.98deg, #5674f7 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%), #35adda;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #5674f7 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%), #35adda;
  color: #535252;
  // background: linear-gradient(59.98deg, #5674f7 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%), #35adda;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.arrow-down {
  display: flex;
  width: 0.9rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: -0.25rem;
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
}

.img {
  width: 9rem;
  height: 8.3rem;
}

.fontWeightTitle {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.home__middle {
  width: 100%;

  &-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 80rem;
  }

  &-box-container-heading {
    color: #222;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  &-box-container-subheading {
    color: #222;
  }

  &-arch-section {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 26rem;

    img {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: -99;
    }

    &--sign__button {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -0.5rem;
      width: 13rem;
      height: 5rem;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 3rem;
      background: #fd7d7d !important;
      color: #fff !important;
      padding: 0.8rem;
      border: none;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .czechbusinesscloud {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 7rem;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 2.4rem;
      line-height: 3rem;
      color: #fff;

      .businesscloud {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
      }
    }
  }

  &-popular-button {
    max-width: 20rem;

    button {
      width: 13rem;
      height: 5rem;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
      background: #fff;
      color: #222;
      padding: 0.8rem;
      border: 1px solid #222;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: bold;
      border-radius: 3rem;
    }
  }

  & .home__middle-container {
    & .home__middle-box {
      text-align: center;
      width: 32rem;
      height: 34rem;
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0 0 1.5rem rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.35);
      padding: 1.6rem;
      border-radius: 8px;

      &-button {
        width: 90%;
        height: 30px;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 3rem;
        color: #0486fe;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        border: none;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        line-height: 2rem;
        font-style: normal;
      }
    }

    & .home__middle-box-icon-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      width: 6rem;
      height: 6rem;
      background: #0486fe;
      border-radius: 3rem;

      & .home__middle-box-icon--glass {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1.4rem;
        left: 1.2rem;
      }

      & .home__middle-box-icon--question {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1.4rem;
        left: 1.8rem;
      }
    }
  }

  .home__button-container {
    width: 20rem;
  }
}

#home--step-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 4rem 0;
  padding-bottom: 8rem;

  & .info-box__description {
    color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .info-box {
    width: 45rem;
    border: none;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 1rem;

    & .info-box__header {
      width: 100%;
      color: #fff;

      & .info-box__heading {
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
      }
    }

    & .info-box__button--description {
      color: #686767;
      text-align: center;
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 3rem;
      border: none;
      padding: 1rem 1.3rem;
      margin-top: 2rem;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}

#home--step-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  & .info-box__description {
    color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  .info-box {
    width: 45rem;
    border: none;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 1rem;

    & .info-box__header {
      width: 100%;
      color: #fff;

      & .info-box__heading {
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
      }
    }

    & .info-box__button--description {
      color: #686767;
      text-align: center;
      width: 25rem;
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 3rem;
      border: none;
      padding: 1rem 1.3rem;
      margin-top: 2rem;
    }
  }
}

#categories {
  // background: rgba(228, 225, 225, 0.424);
  // background: linear-gradient(59.98deg, #5674f7 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%), #35adda;
  padding: 5rem 10rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 18rem;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.categories-heading h2 {
  color: #535252;
}

.info-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 20rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 1rem solid rgba(205, 184, 223, 0.739);
}

.info-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.heading {
  color: #0486fe;
  height: 6rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.heading-top {
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.icon {
  //color: rgba(0, 214, 170, 0.85);
  color: #c7c5c5ab;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 13.6rem);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 13.6rem);
  grid-gap: 3.5rem;

  .gallery-caption {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .gallery-box {
    background: white;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 1.6rem;
    max-width: 16rem;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
}

button {
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
  }
}

:host-context {
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.step1 {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif;

  .step1-text {
    text-align: left;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 3%;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: normal;

    h2 {
      color: #2e2e2e;
      padding-bottom: 2rem;
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 2.2rem;
    }

    p {
      padding-top: 1rem;
      color: #2e2e2e;
      font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      line-height: 1.7rem;
    }
  }

  .step1-graph {
    align-items: center;
    float: right;
    padding: 2%;

    // #step3 {
    //   //padding-top: 3%;
    //  // padding-bottom: 3%;
    // }

    .container {
      min-height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 12%;
      padding-bottom: 12%;
    }
  }
}

.graphic-div {
  margin-top: -14rem;
}

.graphic {
  margin-top: -48rem;
  margin-left: 145rem;
  width: 27.7%;
}

.container-right {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  padding-top: 12%;
  padding-bottom: 12%;
  background: url(/assets/images/homepage/glass-right.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  background-position: right;
  top: -8.1rem;
}

.step2 {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;

  .step2-text {
    text-align: left;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2%;

    h2 {
      color: #2e2e2e;
      padding-bottom: 2rem;
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 2.2rem;
    }

    p {
      padding-top: 1rem;
      color: #2e2e2e;
      font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      line-height: 1.7rem;
    }
  }

  .step2-graph {
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 100%;

    #step3 {
      padding-top: 3%;
      padding-bottom: 3%;
    }

    .container {
      min-height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 12%;
      padding-bottom: 12%;
    }
  }
}

.container-left {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  padding-top: 12%;
  padding-bottom: 12%;
  background: url(/assets/images/homepage/glass-left.svg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: left;
  background-position: left;
  top: -5rem;
}

.catalog__button {
  width: 13rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
  color: #0486fe;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  margin: 1.6rem 0;
  border: 1px solid #0486fe;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;

  a {
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="typography" id="home">
    <app-nav>
      <div class="header">
  
        <div class="header__container">
          <app-header
            (search)="handleSearch($event)"
            (searchApps)="searchApps($event)"
            [filteredApps]="filteredApps"
            [isLoading]="isLoading">
          </app-header>
        </div>
  
        <section class="home__middle"
          fxLayout="column"
          fxLayoutGap="2rem"
          fxLayoutGap.xs="1rem"
          fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxFlexFill>
          <div class="home__middle-container"
            fxLayout="row"
            fxLayout.lt-sm="column"
            fxLayoutGap.xs="1rem"
            fxLayoutGap="6rem"
            fxLayoutAlign="center center"
            fxFlexFill>
  
            <div class="home__middle-box"
              fxLayout="column"
              fxLayoutAlign="center center"
              fxLayoutGap="1rem">
  
              <div>
                <img class="img"
                  src="assets/images/homepage/089-telescope.png">
              </div>
              <div>
                <h2
                  class="home__middle-box-container-heading mat-subheading-2">
                  {{ 'home.looking-for-a-specific-software' | translate }}
                </h2>
              </div>
              <p
                class="home__middle-box-container-subheading mat-subheading-1 ">
                {{ 'home.browse-the-categories' | translate }}<br>
                {{ 'home.catalogue' | translate }}<br>
                {{ 'home.help' | translate }}<br>
                {{ 'home.challenges' | translate }}
              </p>
              <button
                class="home__middle-box-button"
                routerLink="/browse"
                style="cursor: pointer;">
                {{ 'home.browse-catagories' | translate }}
              </button>
            </div>
  
            <div
              class="home__middle-box"
              fxLayout="column"
              fxLayoutAlign="center center"
              fxLayoutGap="2rem">
              <div>
                <img class="img"
                  src="assets/images/homepage/023-idea.png">
              </div>
              <h2
                class="home__middle-box-container-heading mat-subheading-2">
                {{ 'home.are-you-not-sure' | translate }}
              </h2>
              <p
                class="home__middle-box-container-subheading mat-subheading-1">
                {{ 'home.do-you-have-specific-challenge' | translate }}<br>
                {{ 'home.advice' | translate }}<br>
                {{ 'home.suits' | translate }}
              </p>
              <button
                class="home__middle-box-button"
                (click)="getRecommendationsClick()"
                id="home__middle-box-button"
                style="cursor: pointer;">
                {{ 'home.get-recommendations' | translate }}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="home__middle-popular-button">
            <button
              (click)="scroll(target)">
              Popular categories
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="arrow-down">
            <img src="assets/images/Vector.png"
              class="vector">
          </div>
          <div class="home__middle-arch-section"
            fxLayout="column"
            fxLayoutAlign="center center"
            fxLayoutGap="2rem">
            <div
              class="czechbusinesscloud">czech<span
                class="businesscloud">business</span>cloud
              and app store for your business</div>
            <button
              class="home__middle-arch-section--sign__button"
              (click)="scroll(target)">
              Sign Up
            </button>
            <img src="assets/images/background.svg">
          </div>
          <div class="graphic-div">
            <img src="/assets/images/Graphic.svg" class="graphic">
        </div>
        </section>
      </div>
      <!-- <div>
          <img src="/assets/images/Vector1.png" class="vectorsvg">
      </div> -->
  
      <section class="steps-container">
        <div class="step1" fxLayout="row wrap"
          fxLayout.lt-md="column-reverse"
          fxLayoutGap="32px"
          fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">
          <div class="step1-text"
            fxFlex="0 1 calc(33% - 32px)"
            fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)"
            fxFlex.lt-sm="100%">
            <span
              class="mat-subheading-2 fontWeightTitle">
              {{ 'home.step1-complete-questionnaire' | translate }}
            </span>
            <p>
              {{ 'home.tell-us-something-about-your-business' | translate }}
            </p>
            <p>
              {{ 'home.looking-for-package' | translate }}
            </p>
            <p>
              {{ 'home.are-you-overwhelmed' | translate }}
            </p>
            <div class="button">
              <button class="catalog__button"
                (click)="goToQuestionnaireClick()">
                {{ 'home.go-to-questionnaire' | translate }}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="step1-graph"
            fxFlex="0 1 calc(35% - 2px)"
            fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)"
            fxFlex.lt-sm="100%">
            <div class="container" fxLayout="row"
              fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="1%"
              fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">
              <img
                src="assets/images/homepage/026-curriculum-1.png"
                width="44.64%" height="44.64%">
            </div>
            <div class="container-right" fxLayout="row"
            fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="1%"
            fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center" style="margin-left: -20rem; margin-top: -37rem;">
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="step2" fxLayout="row wrap"
          fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutGap="32px"
          fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">
          <div class="container-left" fxLayout="row"
          fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="1%"
          fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center" style="margin-left: -53rem; margin-top: -37rem;">
        </div>
          <div class="step2-graph"
            fxFlex="0 1 calc(35% - 2px)"
            fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)"
            fxFlex.lt-sm="100%">
            <div class="container" fxLayout="row"
              fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="1%"
              fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">
              <img
                src="assets/images/homepage/074-employee-3.png"
                width="44.64%" height="44.64%">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="step2-text"
            fxFlex="0 1 calc(32% - 32px)"
            fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)"
            fxFlex.lt-sm="100%">
            <span
              class="mat-subheading-2 fontWeightTitle">
              {{ 'home.step2-check-result' | translate }}
            </span>
            <p>
              {{ 'home.check-the-recommended-apps' | translate }}
            </p>
            <p>
              {{ 'home.browse-the-apps-for-your-need' | translate }}
            </p>
            <div class="button">
              <button class="catalog__button"
                (click)="getRecommendationsClick()">
                {{ 'home.get-recommended-apps' | translate }}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="steps-container">
        <div class="step1" fxLayout="row wrap"
          fxLayout.lt-md="column-reverse"
          fxLayoutGap="32px"
          fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">
          <div class="step1-text"
            fxFlex="0 1 calc(33% - 32px)"
            fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)"
            fxFlex.lt-sm="100%">
            <span
              class="mat-subheading-2 fontWeightTitle">
              {{ 'home.step3-read-reviews' | translate }}
            </span>
            <p>
              {{ 'home.read-what-other-think' | translate }}
            </p>
            <p>
              {{ 'home.simple-star-ranking' | translate }}
            </p>
            <div class="button">
              <button class="catalog__button"
                (click)="goToCatalogueClick()">
                {{ 'home.see-reviews' | translate }}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="step1-graph"
            fxFlex="0 1 calc(35% - 2px)"
            fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)"
            fxFlex.lt-sm="100%">
            <div class="container" fxLayout="row"
              fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="1%"
              fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">
              <img
                src="assets/images/homepage/024-businessman-20.png"
                width="44.64%" height="44.64%"
                id="step3">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="step2" fxLayout="row wrap"
          fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutGap="32px"
          fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">
          <div class="step2-graph"
            fxFlex="0 1 calc(35% - 2px)"
            fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)"
            fxFlex.lt-sm="100%">
            <div class="container" fxLayout="row"
              fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="1%"
              fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">
              <img
                src="assets/images/homepage/040-launch.png"
                width="44.64%" height="44.64%">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="step2-text"
            fxFlex="0 1 calc(35% - 32px)"
            fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)"
            fxFlex.lt-sm="100%">
            <span
              class="mat-subheading-2 fontWeightTitle">
              {{ 'home.step4-start-using-the-app' | translate }}
            </span>
            <p>
              {{ 'home.now-start-use-app' | translate }}
            </p>
            <p>
              {{ 'home.no-need-to-download-apps' | translate }}
            </p>
            <div class="button">
              <button class="catalog__button"
                (click)="goToCatalogueClick()">
                {{ 'home.get-my-apps' | translate }}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <div #target>
        <app-listing>
        </app-listing>
      </div>
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </app-nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add only relevant code. And show what do you mean with _the curve image they are not responsive_

Comment: I think all the code is needed cause they are elements inside elements and you need the parent also. the explained for curve I will do it on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap grid layout and should try to keep your divs within columns. You can find tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp). To align three divs side by side:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    DIV CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    DIV CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    DIV CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to make your own CSS and do not depend upon any library for CSS, because you would be easily able to understand your own code rather than a library. And speaking of images, give some effort on HTML5 Canvas. You will be able to create such patterns, no need for images.

Comment: I don't have much time for this I need to finish I will use  @media only screen  just for mobile and then if I have time I will try to make it on my own anyway thanks